# GTK# Gtk-WARNING Invalid text buffer iterator

Tags: c#, gtk#

My program work as expect but getting warning. how i should handle this warning?

I getting warning like:

> (NoteHex:84876): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:48:54.777: Invalid text buffer iterator: either the iterator is uninitialized, or the characters/pixbufs/widgets in the buffer have been modified since the iterator was created.
> You must use marks, character numbers, or line numbers to preserve a position across buffer modifications.
> You can apply tags and insert marks without invalidating your iterators,
> but any mutation that affects 'indexable' buffer contents (contents that can be referred to by character offset)
> will invalidate all outstanding iterators

My Code

```cs
 void OnTextChanged1(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is not TextBuffer buffer)
            return;

        int cursorOffset = 0;
        textView1.Buffer.Changed -= OnTextChanged1;
        cursorOffset = textView1.Buffer.CursorPosition;
        string text = buffer.Text.ToUpper();
        buffer.Text = text;
        textView1.Buffer.PlaceCursor(textView1.Buffer.GetIterAtOffset(cursorOffset));
        textView1.Buffer.Changed += OnTextChanged1;
      
    }
```